# Aws Hosting with Godaddy Domain and SSL to work with cloudflare

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare, godaddy-api

We have AWS EC2 instance where we have hosting of our website and we have domain and SSL from godaddy with cloudflare for cache policy.

Now we want to integrate ssl with our website but we are clueless regarding how to do this process with cloudflare as there are three different service providers like AWS, Godaddy and Cloudflare so it would be great if someone could help us how to deal with that.

Answer (score -1):

The question is too generic (you don't mention what web server, or OS are using), let alone mentioning there are tons of documentation already on how to set up SSL in the most popular web servers: Apache and Nginx. One thing that I suggest, is that, if you are using Elastic Load Balancing, then you can use ACM service to deploy an SSL certificate, and attach it to your load balancer. It's the easiest, and cheapest way to do it. 
[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request-public.html) on how to deploy a free SSL certificate managed by AWS, and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/associate-acm-certificate-alb-nlb/) on how to attach it to the load balancer.

if you are not using load balancing, or need to implement fully end-to-end encryption, or simply don't want to do it this way, you will probably need to look into how to set up SSL on the web server you are using. An example can be found in https://www.digicert.com/csr-ssl-installation/apache-openssl.htm, but since you didn't specify what OS or webserver you are using, we can't really say much.